# How to get data from database which has been publish in Azure through bot application in visual C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I created a bot application by using bot framework in visual c# and I published it in Azure. My database also in Azure. I give the CompanyId, TenantId, SiteId and Bandid via bot, then should reply as CompanyName and Address from database. It written in TestData.cs class. 
I attached my TestAPIController also and I want to get the data from database into bot application. How to code my RootDialog.cs ?

```
public class TestAPIController : ApiController
{

    [HttpGet]
    public IHttpActionResult Get(string TenantId, string CompanyId, string SiteId, string BandId)
    {
        TestData TestData = new TestData();
        var TestBusiness = TestData.Select(TenantId, CompanyId, SiteId, BandId);

        return Ok(TestBusiness);
    }

}    

public class TestData :DBConnection
{

    public List<TestBusiness> Select(string TenantId, string CompanyId, string SiteId, string BandId)
    {
        List<TestBusiness> list = new List<TestBusiness>();
        this.StoredProcedure = "RESQBOTGetCompanywiseData";
        AddParameter("TenantId", TenantId);
        AddParameter("CompanyId", CompanyId);
        AddParameter("SiteId", SiteId);
        AddParameter("BandId", BandId);
        DataTable dt = this.ExecuteSelect();
        foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Select())
        {
            TestBusiness item = new TestBusiness();
            item.CompanyName = dr["CompanyName"].ToString();
            item.Address = dr["Address"].ToString();
            list.Add(item);
        }
        return list;


    }
}
```

Comment: have you got the info you wna t

Answer (score 0):

you have to make use of `HttpClient` that allows you to call webapi and get data below is example code

```
using(var client = newHttpClient())  
{  
    client.BaseAddress = newUri("http://localhost:55587/");  
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();  
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add
              (newMediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));  
    //GET Method  
    HttpResponseMessage response = 
              await client.GetAsync("GetAllRows/1/1/1/1");  
    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)  
    {  
    }  
}
```

---

you also need to set route in you web api as below , and pass all parameter when calling this method

```
[Route("GetAllRows/{TenantId}/{CompanyId}/{SiteId}/{BandId}")]
 public IHttpActionResult Get(string TenantId, string CompanyId,
                   string SiteId, string BandId)
{
}
```

also configure you webapi for route attribute based routing

```
   public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

       }
```

Follow this article : https://dzone.com/articles/web-api-with-httpclient-or-consume-web-api-from-co

Comment: Thank you @Pranay for your clarification. I set route and configure web api for route also. Please can you explain where is a place that coding user() in my code(Which Controller or Dialog file) and also What is the path of "application/json".

Comment: @KoshilaDilrukshi - hi not getting you..if you want to create class called use in webapi then create class in model folder, other than than "application/json" is way to specify that you want response back in json format

Comment: sorry for mistake not user(), It should be using(var client = newHttpClient()) that related your code. Please explain me, Where is the place that writing using() in my code.

Comment: @KoshilaDilrukshi - you need to put that in you console or winform or wpf application ...just to check that your service is returning value

Comment: @KoshilaDilrukshi - please go here : https://dzone.com/articles/web-api-with-httpclient-or-consume-web-api-from-co you will get detail

Answer (score 0):

In the RootDialog.cs, I created object that instance of TestAPIController. Then call that one and pass inputs as parameters. I show the data that are in first data of the Database.

```
TestAPIController Test = new TestAPIController();
returnData = Test.Get(TenantId, CompanyId, SiteId, BandId);

string companyName = returnData[0].CompanyName.ToString();
string address= returnData[0].Address.ToString();

await context.PostAsync("Company Name = "+ companyName + " and It's address is "+ address);
```